# How to inject specific param according to the URL?

Tags: php, symfony

Developping a Symfony 3 app, I need to have a multi-website according to the URL.
Here's my parameters.yml file:

```
...
dbname_cda: my-website-cda
dbname_pts: my-website-pts
dbname_vis: my-website-vis
...
```

and here's the config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: my-website
        connections:
            my-website:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%dbhost%"
                port:     "%dbport%"
                dbname:   "%_______%"
                user:     "%dbuser%"
                password: "%dbpassword%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

`https://my-website.com/cda` will inject the param `dbname_cda`.

`https://my-website.com/pts` will inject the param `dbname_pts`.

`https://my-website.com/vis` will inject the param `dbname_vis`.

Actually, it's the same website except that the data is loaded from different databases according to the URL.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That would be easier to achieve with subdomains: `cda.my-website.com` as you could make the dbname var specific in each vhost.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, i'm not allowed to create subdomains within the company.. :/ That's why i'm trying to find a workaround

Comment: Symfony works by "compiling" all of the configuration files (including your parameters) into several big cached classes.  You cannot inject a parameter on a request basis.  Just won't work.  I'm afraid you will need to dig into the whole service/configuration system.  Essentially you will need to make a request listener which actually creates a doctrine connection and figure out how to use it as needed.  Little bit advanced.  Do some searching for multi tenant systems for more details.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad for your details.

Comment: maybe just have all 3 dbconnections defined, and use a simple routing param and request listener, to set the correct doctrine connection on some service, which you will then use in your controllers to fetch your data from..    if you understand what im trying to say ..

Comment: Hi there, thanks. I got what you mean but that would be a mess to do so 'cause I have a plenty of controllers :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to solve your problem, considering the fact that you can't dynamically inject a variable, as these configuration variables are defined at Symfony's "compile time".

Declare first all your connections in `app/config/config.yml` (I only take your `cda` and `pts` connections):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: cda
        connections:
            cda:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_cda_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
            pts:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_pts_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: cda
        entity_managers:
            cda:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: cda
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
            pts:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: pts
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
```

Then, declare your own version of the `doctrine` service in `app/config/services.yml`. This version will replace the one defined by Symfony.

```
services:
    # ...

    doctrine_url_switcher:
        class: AppBundle\Doctrine\Registry
        decorates: doctrine
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine_url_switcher.inner' # Original Doctrine service
            - '@request_stack'
        public: false
```

I am using here the [service decoration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) mechanism of Symfony to define a new version of the `doctrine` service.

Now, define the `AppBundle\Doctrine\Registry` class, that extends Symfony's one and will make use of the `RequestStack` when asking for the default entity manager or connection:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as BaseRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Registry extends BaseRegistry
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(BaseRegistry $baseRegistry, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $baseRegistry->container,
            $baseRegistry->getConnectionNames(),
            $baseRegistry->getManagerNames(),
            $baseRegistry->getDefaultConnectionName(),
            $baseRegistry->getDefaultManagerName()
        );

        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConnection($name = null)
    {
        $connection = null;
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        if ($request) {
            $path = $request->getPathInfo();

            if (preg_match(':^/cda:', $path)) {
                $connection = 'cda';
            } elseif (preg_match(':^/pts:', $path)) {
                $connection = 'pts';
            }
        }

        return parent::getConnection($connection);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getManager($name = null)
    {
        $manager = null;
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        if ($request) {
            $path = $request->getPathInfo();

            if (preg_match(':^/cda:', $path)) {
                $manager = 'cda';
            } elseif (preg_match(':^/pts:', $path)) {
                $manager = 'pts';
            }
        }

        return parent::getManager($manager);
    }
}
```

By overriding methods of the `Registry` class, we make use of the request object to determine which entity manager or which connection should be used. Parent methods are called with the specific entity manager name or connection name, depending on the URL. In case the URL could not help find which one to use, the default ones (defined in `config.yml` are used).

Comment: I tested it myself and it worked :) My first solution was to use a service factory to configure the doctrine service, which was a slightly more elegant solution, but there were caveats because of the RequestStack which was not systematically initialised. I preferred this solution as a result.

Comment: It seems like my solution worked for you! That's great :)

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect :)